# How are these template arguments interpreted and used?

Tags: c++, templates

Can some one please explain me what is exactly happening in the following code

```
template <template <typename, typename...> class Holder, typename retType,typename... T>
    class EventListener<Holder<retType(T...)>> 
    {
      friend class Holder<retType(T...)>;
      typedef Holder<retType(T...)> HolderType;
       private:
      HolderType* _Holder;
    }
```

I just would like to know that what exactly mentioned by Holder, both retType and T are typenames. then how retType(T...) defined...?

Comment: `retType(T...)` is a function type that returns `retType` and takes a pack of `T`. For example: `int(bool, char, int)` or `void()`

Answer (score 0):

The template argument

```
template <typename, typename...> class Holder
```

is a *template template argument*. It means that the template argument should be a class template that can be parameterized over a single type followed by a list of template type arguments. For example, if you had a template like

```
template <typename, typename... Args> class ImAVariadicTemplate {
    // ...
};
```

You could instantiate the first template argument by passing in `ImAVariadicTemplate`.

That next bit, `retType(T...)`, means "the type of a function whose return type is `retType` and whose argument types are specified by the list of types given in the parameter pack `T`. For example, if `retType` is `int` and `T` is the list `double, float, short`, then this expands out to the type `int(double, float, short)`, the type of a function taking in a `double`, a `float`, and a `short` and returning an `int`. (The syntax here can be quite confusing, since it looks like you're calling a function named `retType` when you're really talking about a type of a function).

Putting these together, the syntax

```
Holder<retType(T...)>
```

means "instantiate the `Holder` template using as the type the type of a function that takes in a series of arguments whose type is given by the list of types in `T` and returns a `retType`." Rolls right off the tongue. :-)